# How to make cross origin calls in apostrophe cms

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors, apostrophe, apostrophe-cms

I am trying to make a CORS call to my API.

```
$.ajax({
        url: baseURL + '?' + qString,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (response) {
            cb(null, response.objects);
        },
        failure: function (err) {
            failureHandler(err);
            cb(err);
        },
    });
```

but I am getting an error

`Request header field X-XSRF-TOKEN is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

I even tried to disable CRFS by passing this in app.js

```
'apostrophe-express': {
  csrf: false,
},
```

But it didn't do anything, is there a way I can disable this behavior and make CORS API calls.

Comment: Hi Priyansh, is the URL you are accessing on the same site? I'm wondering if we are forcing this feature on cross-domain API calls. If we are, that's a bug we need to fix. If it's a call to the same website though, you shouldn't have a problem because of our XSRF middleware (and the features we have for creating exceptions to it for custom routes). Of course those exception features aren't much use if you're talking to someone else's webserver... which is why it might be a bug we must fix.

Comment: baseURL here is not on the same site, which means you might be forcing this feature on CORS calls

Comment: @TomBoutell this PR fixes this issue https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/pull/1300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have accepted your PR exempting cross-origin calls, so beginning with the next release (likely tomorrow), this issue will be resolved and should not face the next developer.

Comment: This was published to npm.